# Is it possible to broadcast in Unity (Android, iOS)[not 1 to 1] via agora.io?

Tags: agora.io

We are working on a game which we'll have a 1 broadcaster and all of our users are audiences. Is it possible to broadcast on Unity clients (Android, iOS) via Agora.io Unity video sdk (not one to one call, it's going be 1 to all call)

I've tried not broadcasting from users and using only 1 broadcaster app and the clients are on audience state but it seems like being in audience or broadcaster status does not change anything. App continues to broadcast from clients too. I don't want to broadcast from client. I just want to watch live stream of the one broadcaster from it.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do a 1-to-many broadcast using Agora's Unity SDK. First you need to set the channel profile to `CHANNEL_PROFILE_GAME_COMMAND_MODE`

```
public int SetChannelProfile(CHANNEL_PROFILE_GAME_COMMAND_MODE);
```

And then set the user's `clientRole`

```
public int SetClientRole(CLIENT_ROLE);
```

and set the roles using

- CLIENT_ROLE_BROADCASTER = 1: Broadcaster
- CLIENT_ROLE_AUDIENCE = 2: Audience( default)

Also when you call the `EnableVideo` only do this on the Broadcaster, since audience won't need to publish their stream.